# Facebook API - reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request for 1 row

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following logic for my ad insights request:
If Facebook asks me to reduce the amount of data I'm requesting, I half the date range. If the date range is the same, I half the `limit`.

It gets to the point I send this request:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{account}/insights?level=ad&time_increment=1&limit=1&time_range={"since":"2019-03-29","until":"2019-03-29"}&breakdowns=country&after=MjMwNwZDZD

But I still get that error:

> Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request

There is no more reducing I can do.

Note, that this only happens sometimes.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351125/facebook-graphapi-reduce-amount-of-data-with-limit

Comment: Thanks, but no. As you can see, I am using since/until of the same day, and limit of 1, so my request does agree with that answer, it is just still not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to avoid the error is when you only request 1 item (`limit=1`) to start splitting the `fields` and request half the `fields` in each request.

Another way is to run an async report, which should not have such a low time limit.

**Official Facebook API team response:**

> It looks like you are requesting a lot of fields, this is likely the
>   cause of this error. This will cause the request to time-out.
>
> Could you try using asynchronous requests as described here:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/#asynchronous?
>
> Async requests have a much longer time limit, this will likely resolve
>   your issue.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{groupID}/feed?fields=from,full_picture,id,name,caption,message&limit=1

I am requesting this only this but didnt working

Comment: I also face the same problem requesting only 1 post from the feed:

https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{group-id}/feed?fields=object_id,message,paging,permalink_url,attachments&limit=1

I am pretty sure the same used to work before. I read in other posts that FB has a known bug, but it seems to have been for a long time, I have a hard time believing it.
Any suggestion?